# Reduce space between first histogram bar and y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a histogram [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obuy5.jpg) which I made using the following:

```
import pylab as pl

fd = FreqDist(list(industries))
X = np.arange(len(fd))
pl.bar(X, fd.values(), align='center', width=0.15)
pl.xticks(X, fd.keys(), rotation=90)
pl.tick_params(labelsize=8)
ymax = max(fd.values()) + 1
pl.ylim(0, ymax)
pl.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
pl.savefig('internalDoorCount.jpg')
```

However I need the gap to reduce between the y-axis and the first histogram bar. Also how do you prevent overlapping of text?

Comment: please ask exactly one question per question.  This prevents situations like this where there are two answers, each of which addresses one of your two questions, but you can only accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to avoid overlapping of the text by using this function:

`pl.gcf().autofmt_xdate(bottom=0.3, rotation=-30, ha="left")`

It's created for rotating date tick labels, but it should work good here. But you most probably have to either reduce the font size, and/or increase the width of your figure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `pl` is `matplotlib.pyplot`, use `pl.xlim`. Because I'm not sure what values your x-axis takes, try

```
pl.xlim(min(X), max(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot upvote and I'm amazed how old answers here are still helpful. So, as I still don't have points to comment, I'm answering here to correct a typo from @wflynny and say his answer is simple and works. The actual beginning of the code is "plt", instead of "pl":

```
plt.xlim(min(x),max(x))
```

The complete documentation is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).